# How to determine the probability of even number of ones in a fair coin toss?

Tags: probability

A {0,1} coin is tossed m-1 times (assume m is >= 2). We have a set of events $A_1,A_2,A_3,...$

where $A_k$ is the event that the kth outcome is 1 (where k=1,2,...,m-1).

$A_m$ is the event that there are an even number of 1's occurred among the m-1 tosses.

How would I show that $P(A_k) = 0.5, P(A_k\cap A_l) = 0.25,$ and $P(A_k\cap A_l \cap A_p) $ for all ${k,l,p}$ $\in {1,2,3,...,n}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(A_k)=0.5$ is axiomatic from your specification that the toss is "fair".

$$P(A_k\cap A_l)=P(A_k)P(A_l|A_k)$$

$A_k$ and $A_l$ are independent events if $k\ne l$ $(P(A_l|A_k)=P(A_l))$ and (highly) dependent if $k=l$ $(P(A_l|A_k)=1)$ (because they are the same event). So:

$$P(A_k\cap A_l)=\begin{cases}
0.5 \times 0.5 = 0.25, &k\ne l\\
0.5 \times 1 = 0.5, &k= l\\
\end{cases}$$

With this, you can now extend it to a third case.

Given the question you posed, the definition of $A_m$ is not needed.